# Laravel 5 UserController Throwing Error FatalErrorException

Tags: php, laravel, controller, namespaces, laravel-5

I have a problem using laravel 5.0 Controller. I am building RESTFul function that triggers UserController.

Herewith my `routes.php`

```
Route::post('user/create', 'UserController@create');
```

I POST the input user using cURL using this command

```
curl -d 'fname=randy&lname=tan&id_location=1&email=randy@randytan.me&password=randytan&remember_token=Y&created_at=2015-03-03' localhost:8000/user/create
```

and this is my create method on UserController

```
public function create()
    {
        //function to create user.
        $userAccounts = new \App\User;
        $userAccounts->fname = Request::post('fname');
        $userAccounts->lname = Request::post('lname');
        $userAccounts->id_location = Request::post('id_location');
        $userAccounts->email = Request::post('email');
        $userAccounts->password = Hash::make(Request::post('password'));
        $userAccounts->created_at = Request::post('created_at');

        $userAccounts->save();

        return Response::json(array(
                'error' => false,
                'user'  => $userAccounts->fname . " " . $userAccounts->lname
            ), 200);

    }
```

But somehow i trigger the cURL command, it is throwing FatalErrorException, which says, `Class &#039;App\User&#039; not found`

I have tried change the syntax `$userAccounts = new User;` but still no luck,

Any ideas?

Thanks before.

===============================
**UPDATE**

Herewith the all source code from my controller

```
<?php namespace randytan\Http\Controllers;

use randytan\Http\Requests;
use randytan\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //function to get index of user. basically get the user token.
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //function to create user.
        $userAccounts = new App\User;
        $userAccounts->fname = Request::post('fname');
        $userAccounts->lname = Request::post('lname');
        $userAccounts->id_location = Request::post('id_location');
        $userAccounts->email = Request::post('email');
        $userAccounts->password = Hash::make(Request::post('password'));
        $userAccounts->created_at = Request::post('created_at');

        $userAccounts->save();

        return Response::json(array(
                'error' => false,
                'user'  => $userAccounts->fname . " " . $userAccounts->lname
            ), 200);

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //function store user acounts
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //function to get user resources
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //function to edit the user.
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //function to update the user accounts
        $userAccountDetails = User::where('id', $id)->get();

        /* get details of user from the GET parameter */
        $username = "randy";

        if($userAccountDetails){
            var_dump("123");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update Connection Between Two User
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function follows($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Laravel 5 uses PSR-4 autoloaders. Did you place use App\User at the top of your code file? Did you move the User model? You're also looking in the global namespace for App. Try removing \ from the beginning

Comment: Does it exists in `App` directory? If yes, post the full controller code, maybe the error is about other line.

Comment: @Zarathuztra no, I do not place App\User at the top of my files and i do not move the user model to another folder.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek i posted the full source code. please kindly look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code and namespaces, your `User` class is probably in `randytan` namespace, so you should use:

```
$userAccounts = new randytan\User;
```

to create your user. The same will be for your `update` method, so it's better if you add

```
use randytan\User;
```

before:

```
class UserController
```

and now you can use `User` anywhere inside this class

Comment: is configured namespace overriding my current `app` path?

Comment: @randytan It seems you changed your default `App` namespace into `randytan` so everything you normally have in `App` namespace you have in `randytan` namespace

Comment: thanks Marcin, for the function `Input::` when i trigger from a method, it also throws notFound, should i also override this?

Comment: @randytan For other classes/facades like Request, probably Input, you should import them before your class, for example `use Input;` or use `\Input::something()` syntax

Comment: thanks buddy for your explanation. Now understand why all the parameter is not working properly. :)